# On declaring html 5 DTD some css styles are not computing any browser

Tags: css, html

Top and right styles of "#help" are not computed in any browser on declaring doctype as 
Html code is:

```
    <div id="events">
        <img src="media/Event icon.png" alt="events" id="events_img">
    </div>
    <div id="colors" >
         <img src="media/CULTURAL.png" alt="Colours" id="Colors_img">
    </div>
    <div id="hospitality">
      <img src="media/117016-matte-blue-and-white-square-icon-business-notepad.png" alt="hospitality" id="hospitality_img">
    </div>
    <div id="help">
        <img id="help_img" src="media/Help.png" alt="help">
    </div>
    <img src="media/cadbell.fw.png" alt="cadbell" id="cadbell">
    <img src="media/cadbell2.fw.png" alt="cadbell" id="cadbell2">
    <img src="media/Bird-blue-icon.png" alt="angry bird" id="angry_bird">   

   <div id='bottom-div'></div>


       <img src="media/stick.fw.png" alt="stick" id="stick"> 
       <span id="dev"><b>Developed by:&nbsp </b><a href='#'>D Akhil Reddy</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have given only css style for #help and its sub element #help_img , top and right are not working,
css styles of #help:

```
#help{
position: absolute;
right: 320;
top: 390;
cursor: pointer;
width: 137px;
}
#help_img{
position:absolute;
left:10px;
}
```

Comment: There is no “html 5 DTD”. You probably mean that you inserted the string `<!doctype html>` at the start of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html), CSS declarations like `right: 320` are interpreted so that the `px` unit is implied. This violates CSS specifications, which require that such declarations be ignored.

If you put `<!doctype html>` or any other doctype string that triggers Standards Mode, things may change quite a lot if the CSS code has errors.

The solution is to fix the CSS code. In this case, it should suffice to replace `320` and `390` by `320px` and `390px`. Use the W3C [CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) to check your CSS code.